# Create a double instance of a service in my angular app

Tags: angular, service

I have a Generic service. I would like to create two instance of this service with different type =>

```
constructor(
  private mapSynchService: 
SynchronizatorService<SynchMapElement, SynchMapElementSubject>,
  private waypointSynchService: 
SynchronizatorService<SynchWaypointElement, SynchWaypointElementSubject>) { }
```

The problem, I thought this would create two different service cause the definition is different, but it is not doing so. But I don't quite understand how I can make those service available in all my module, and get the correct one for the component that need service 1, and same for those who need service 2.

I have seen some post about injection token, but my implementation failed. I tried something like this in the module

```
providers: 
  [{provide: 
    new InjectionToken<SynchronizatorService<SynchWaypointElement, SynchWaypointElementSubject>>()}]
```

But got a lot of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two separate injection tokens for providing separate instances.

Each token works like a unique name to value/class/factory mapping for the Angular DI container. Also make sure the service is marked `@Injectable` for Angular to recognise it.

Example:

```js
// Export unique Injection Token

export const SYNCH_MAP = new InjectionToken<SynchronizatorService<SynchMapElement, SynchMapElementSubject>>('Token for SynchMap');
export const SYNCH_WAYPOINT = new InjectionToken<SynchronizatorService<SynchWaypointElement, SynchWaypointElementSubject>>('Token for SynchWaypoint');

// Using at a module level

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        { provide: SYNCH_MAP, useClass: SynchronizatorService<SynchMapElement, SynchMapElementSubject> }
        { provide: SYNCH_WAYPOINT, useClass: SynchronizatorService<SynchMapElement, SynchMapElementSubject> }
    ]
})


// Injecting in a component 

constructor(
    @Inject(SYNCH_MAP) private instance1: SynchronizatorService<SynchMapElement, SynchMapElementSubject>,
    @Inject(SYNCH_WAYPOINT) private instance2: SynchronizatorService<SynchMapElement, SynchMapElementSubject>,
)
```

IMO, it would be better to use a `useFactory` provider for having more control on initialising the service instances. As I assume your service definition is using a template `<T>`. Please have a look at https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#predefined-tokens-and-multiple-providers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to do what you said, but I get the following error in the providers ngModule ("Value of type 'typeof SynchronizatorService' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?") I try to add new, then I get another bunch of error of type not valid with useClass. I made a similar implementation, if you have time please check 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789714/usefactory-provider-for-separated-service-instance-in-a-module

Comment: Let me try and create a working Stackblitz example.

Comment: I made two here

Comment: the version you said : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tpbsq

what I tried to implement https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htpqms

Comment: Here is a working example using two types `Cat` and `Dog`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j8kgkd The console statements on line 24, 25 will still print `undefined`, but hovering on the `this.instance.myType` will show the correct type. Reason for this is documented on TypeScript docs @ https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html. Please read the last paragraph under the title `Generic Classes` where they explain the generic behaviour at instance side only. So in the `typeof` log will print the correct type only if the `myType` variable is initialised.

Comment: Trying this out, I realised that TS generics are not same as other JAVA or other languages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192204/discussion-between-ashish-gd-and-bobby).