# useFactory Provider for separated service instance in a module

Tags: angular, service

related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788991/create-a-double-instance-of-a-service-in-my-angular-app/55789205#55789205)

I have the following code

```
const MyType1Factory = () => {
  return new MyService<Type1>();
};

export let MyType1Provider =
{
  provide: MyService,
  useFactory: MyType1Factory,
};
```

and

```
const MyType2Factory = () => {
  return new MyService<Type2>();
};

export let MyType2Provider =
{
  provide: MyService,
  useFactory: MyType2Factory,
};
```

Now I try to inject two different instance of this service into a my module so I can access my two instance from any component of this module

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [MyType1Provider , MyType2Provider ]
})
```

but I don't exactly know how to retrieve this instance in my child component.

Also, Is this a correct implementation ?

EDIT :

I also tried to add the following in the module

```
export const MyType2 = new InjectionToken<MyService<Type2>>('Type2');
export const MyType1 = new InjectionToken<MyService<Type1>>('Type1');

  providers: [
    { provide: MyType2, useFactory : MyType2Factory },
    { provide: MyType1 , useFactory: MyType1Factory }
]
```

and the following in the component.

```
  constructor(@Inject(MyType2) private MyType2: MyService<Type2>,
              @Inject(MyType1 ) private MyType1 : MyService<Type1>) { }
```

but this give me

> compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for
>   NavigationIndexComponent: (?, ?).

Here is a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htpqms

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 issues in stackblitz project

write useFactory, instead of useClass, because you are using factory method not class for instantiation.
write token instantiation in different file  not in app.module.ts, it causes circular dependency, because app.module.ts imports my-component.component.ts file and my-component.component.ts imports app.module.ts, put it for example token.ts file and import in app.module and my-component.component from there

```
     import { NgModule, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
     import { SynchronizatorService } from './synchronizator.service';


     export const SYNCH_STRING = new InjectionToken<SynchronizatorService<string, string>>('SynchMapToken');
    export const SYNCH_NUMBER = new InjectionToken<SynchronizatorService<number, number>>('SynchWaypointToken');
```